# Subquery not working in where IN clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Jobcard table
```

| jobcardId | advisorId |
| --- | --- |
| f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1 | [5d414796-935d-414d-8f7a-952c7806d7e3,627433fe-b6ca-465e-be66-f53cbc3c6d86] |

```
User Table
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 5d414796-935d-414d-8f7a-952c7806d7e3 | Adam |
| 627433fe-b6ca-465e-be66-f53cbc3c6d86 | Martin |
| b6ca796t-judk-djdj-djdj-didkdkdksssk | Marry |

Expected Output

| f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1 | Adam,Martin |
| --- | --- |

I have tried below query

First way

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(U.name) name
FROM jobcards J
JOIN users U ON FIND_IN_SET(J.advisor_ids, U.id)
GROUP BY J.id;
```

Second Way

I have formatted advisor_id so that I can use advisor ID in where IN clause like below.

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(advisor_ids,'[',"'"),']',"'"),",","','") AS id from jobcards where id ='f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1'
```

Giving result
'5d414796-935d-414d-8f7a-952c7806d7e3','627433fe-b6ca-465e-be66-f53cbc3c6d86'

If I am using above ID in query directly, it's giving result.

```
SELECT * FROM users U WHERE id IN('5d414796-935d-414d-8f7a-952c7806d7e3','627433fe-b6ca-465e-be66-f53cbc3c6d86')
```

But when I am using first query in where IN clause than not giving result.

```
SELECT * FROM users U WHERE id IN(SELECT replace(replace(replace(advisor_ids,'[',"'"),']',"'"),",","','") AS id from jobcards where id ='f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1')
```

Not giving result.

Comment: Please clarify the problem you are having. At this point you are not even selecting data from you database, you are creating a dynamic column with the replaced value of `advisor_ids` - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a74d8/1721)

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check again

Comment: Consider modifying your database, storing multiples ID's (in a RMDB) isn't a good aproach. Conside creating a table `jobcard_per_advisor` with `jobcard_id` and `advisor_id` as columns.

Comment: Do not work with JSON array using string functions. Use according JSON functions (for example, MEMBER OF, JSON_CONTAINS and so on).

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: You can begin from adding the expected output to your post: that will make everyone clear what you're expecting this query to do, and avoid "*it's not working*" situations under answers.

Comment: Your problem is that the string your subquery is creating is a single string with single quotes and commas making it LOOK like the values you're giving in your working query but it's not the same. The `IN` function needs a set of values, which means your subquery needs to return multiple rows rather than just a string

Comment: What change do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Exploding a string of values in MySQL is tricky and as others have hinted, you should avoid storing related IDs in a single column. You should consider using a pivot table to link your advisors to your jobs. Then you can use a join to get all advisors for a job

Comment: You'd be looking at making a custom function to separate your comma delimited string into values, then you'd have to accept a massive performance loss over a pivot table and a join. So really the answer to your question is to restructure your DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) and please fix the design , you will be facing a lot of issues mostly performance in the future.

As per the question, if `advisorId` column contains the string separated by comma and the `[]` symbols a simple join with find_in_set and replace would give you the desired result.

For huge data the performance would be terrible.

```
SELECT jobcardId, GROUP_CONCAT(U.name) name
FROM jobcards J
JOIN users U ON FIND_IN_SET(U.id,replace(replace(J.advisorId,'[',''),']',''))
GROUP BY J.jobcardId;
```

Result

```
jobcardId                                   name
f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1    Adam,Martin
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/M7ohWd-q)

Comment: @shambhu-sharan:  Please also do note that the parameters used in `FIND_IN_SET()` are in another order than you where using....

Comment: Very slow. If I adding  FIND_IN_SET() in my query. execution time increase from .02s to 22 sec on same record

Comment: @ShambhuSharan I already mentioned **For huge data the performance would be terrible.** , the best solution is to fix table design

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dynamic query to get the result:

```
SET @subqueryResult = (
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(advisor_ids, '[', ''''), ']', ''''), ',', ''',''') AS id 
    FROM 
        jobcards 
    WHERE 
        id = 'f82d6c76-b344-4f58-8fe9-a405c9b968d1'
);

SET @dynamicQuery = CONCAT('
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        users U 
    WHERE 
        id IN (', @subqueryResult, ')
');

PREPARE finalQuery FROM @dynamicQuery;
EXECUTE finalQuery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE finalQuery;
```

Comment: Please explain the answer - How does this solve the question? Code-only answers are not good answers

Comment: What do you mean, that's not the issue - [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/359089)